# Specifying limit and offset in Django QuerySet wont work

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-orm

I'm using Django 1.6.5 and have MySQL's general-query-log on, so I can see the sql hitting MySQL.
And I noticed that Specifying a bigger limit in Django's QuerySet would not work:

```
>>> from blog.models import Author  
>>> len(Author.objects.filter(pk__gt=0)[0:999])
>>> len(Author.objects.all()[0:999])
```

And MySQL's general log showed that both query had `LIMIT 21`.

But a limit smaller than 21 would work, e.g. `len(Author.objects.all()[0:10])` would make a sql with `LIMIT 10`.

Why is that? Is there something I need to configure?

Comment: That only  means there are 21 entries in the database, Note that slice does not throw an error.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

It happens when you make queries from the shell - the `LIMIT` clause is added to stop your terminal filling up with thousands of records when debugging:

> You were printing (or, at least, trying to print) the repr() of the
>   queryset. To avoid people accidentally trying to retrieve and print a
>   million results, we (well, I) changed that to only retrieve and print
>   the first 20 results and print "remainder truncated" if there were more.
>   This is achieved by limiting the query to 21 results (if there are 21
>   results there are more than 20, so we print the "truncated" message).
>   That only happens in the  **repr**() -- i.e. it's only for diagnostic
>   printing. No normal user code has this limit included automatically, so
>   you happily create a queryset that iterates over a million results.

([Source](http://www.mail-archive.com/django-users@googlegroups.com/msg67486.html))

Answer (score 38):

Django implements `OFFSET` using Python’s array-slicing syntax. If you want to offset the first 10 elements and then show the next 5 elements then use it

```
MyModel.objects.all()[OFFSET:OFFSET+LIMIT]
```

For example if you wanted to check 5 authors after an offset of 10 then your code would look something like this:

```
Author.objects.all()[10:15]
```

You can read more about it [here in the official Django doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/queries/#limiting-querysets)

I have also written a blog around this concept, [you can here more here](https://thetldr.tech/how-to-implement-pagination-in-django-using-limit-and-offset/)

Comment: The author literally said he's using this syntax, but asks about wrong limit of 21 records.

Answer (score 6):

The `LIMIT` and `OFFSET` doesn't work in the same way in Django, the way we expect it to work.

For example.

If we have to read next 10 rows starting from 10th row and if we specify :

```
Author.objects.all()[10:10]
```

It will return the empty record list. In order to fetch the next 10 rows, we have to add the offset to the limit.

```
Author.objects.all()[10:10+10]
```

And it will return the record list of next 10 rows starting from the 10th row.

Answer (score 3):

for offset and limit i  used and worked for me :)

```
MyModel.objects.all()[offset:limit]
```

for exapmle:-

```
Post.objects.filter(Post_type=typeId)[1:1]
```

Comment: I think the slice should be `[offset: offset + limit]`.

Comment: but thats not the case @neuront its [offset:limit]

Comment: Think of it as [FROM:TO]

Comment: when I used filter with offset and limit I get this error '>=' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'

Answer (score 1):

I does work, but django uses an iterator. It does not load all objects at once.